# PHP Generator Yield keyword with FTP

Tags: php, csv, ftp, yield, php-5.5

I am using php ftp function to get the filename => filecontent associative array from ftp . And then I loop over this array and perform my operation .

There are many files on server . I just want to know if I can use yield keyword to reduce memory usage while using that data .

Also , I am reading csv files and looping over its rows using the csv function from php . Is it also possible to use Yield keyword there to reduce memory consumption ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are many files on server. I just want to know if I can use yield keyword to reduce memory usage while using that data.

This requires you to test for that. It could be, but you would need to metric the memory usage by comparing both ways. You quickly pre-test by using **DirectoryIterator**, this could spare you to write the **Generator** for a first start.

> Also , I am reading csv files and looping over its rows using the csv function from php . Is it also possible to use Yield keyword there to reduce memory consumption ?

Perhaps, however a Traversable for CSV data is already available with **SplFileObject**, you most likely don't need to re-invent the wheel here.

Using such **Traversable**s allow you to replace them later with your own generator versions. So you should be easily able to compare different iteration strategies.